# Can't install ndiswrapper commons from the cd

Tags: installation, wireless, ndiswrapper

I need to install my wireless driver through Ndisgtk that comes in the Ubuntu CD,I need to install ndiswrapper-common and ndiswrapper-utils first, but when I try to install ndiswrapper-common the install button is disabled, I don't have an internet connection since I don't have wireless, is there another way to install those three packages that I need? ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got around this by opening the cd up in the file finder and searching for a the packages needed and I went to the command line and did a su dpkg -i .deb and it complains about dependencies find and install those and If everything is as it should be it won't complain at any point about packages not being configured properly. Normally in the past I would add the installation cd as a source in the Sources program.  But that method doesn't seem to function as it had in the past.